# How i can implement this Matlab code in C?

Tags: matlab

I need your help to implement this Matlab code in C.

ro=sqrt((c1.*c1).*(c2.*c2).*(c3.*c3));

I know .* is element by element.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: C is a ***strongly*** typed language. Therefore, unlike MATLAB, we first need to know what ***sort*** of variables `c1`, `c2` & `c3` are, and what the corresponding "." and "*" operations mean. Although as mentioned below - they mean element-wise multiplication, the implementation of this will be very dependent on the corresponding C type

Comment: Could you please clarify what the `.` operator means? I understand that `.*` means point-wise / element-wise product but I am not aware of `.` as an operator on its own.

Comment: C1, C2, C3 ->   a matrix of 2048x1 type: double. Problem with copy paste. It's ro=sqrt((c1.*c1).*(c2.*c2).*(c3.*c3));  Sorry

Comment: i don't have "." operator. Just .* (Element-wise multiplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved using a `for` loop to do the elementwise multiplication. I've provided a very simple solution below, although you would have to populate the contents of `C1`, `C2` and `C3` yourself

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double C1, C2, C3[2048] = { 0 }; //Initialise arrays
    double ro[2048] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) { //Iterate through elementwise

        ro[i] = sqrt(C1[i] ^ 2 + C2[i] ^ 2 + C3[i] ^ 2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. I just change + to * but it's perfect. Thanks!

```
double C1[2048]={1,2,3,5,6,7,4,2,5};
double C2[2048]={1,6,3,5,6,2,4,1,6};
double C3[2048]={1,2,1,5,6,4,4,2,2};

int ro[2048] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {

    ro[i] = sqrt((C1[i]*C1[i]) * (C2[i]*C2[i]) * (C3[i]*C3[i]));
}
```

Comment: either works, multiplcation by itself or power of two. for reference, post this update as an edit to your question, not to a duplicate answer